# When something is an “X.*” standard, what does that “X.*” stand for?

Tags: standards

There are multiple standards which is known under `X.` identifier -  [`X.509`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509), [`X.208`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.208) (aka: [`ASN.1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One)) for example.

What does the `X.` stand for? I understand RFC and others, but `X.` is really weird. I cannot find any note about meaning of `X.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s an [ITU-T recommendation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:ITU-T_recommendations). There are various prefixes. The category “X” is, among others, for security-related documents.

> - A: Organization of the work of ITU-T
> - B: Means of expression: definitions, symbols, classification
> - C: General telecommunication statistics
> - D: General tariff principles
> - E: Overall network operation, telephone service, service operation and human factors
> - F: Non-telephone telecommunication services
> - G: Transmission systems and media, digital systems and networks
> - H: Audiovisual and multimedia systems
> - I: Integrated services digital network
> - J: Cable networks and transmission of television, sound programme and other multimedia signals
> - K: Protection against interference
> - L: Construction, installation and protection of cables and other elements of outside plant
> - M: Telecommunication management, including TMN and network maintenance
> - N: Maintenance: international sound programme and television transmission circuits
> - O: Specifications of measuring equipment
> - P: Telephone transmission quality, telephone installations, local line networks
> - Q: Switching and signalling
> - R: Telegraph transmission
> - S: Telegraph services terminal equipment
> - T: Terminals for telematic services
> - U: Telegraph switching
> - V: Data communication over the telephone network
> - X: Data networks, open system communications and security
> - Y: Global information infrastructure, Internet protocol aspects and next-generation networks
> - Z: Languages and general software aspects for telecommunication systems

Comment: I just found this list. I'm now very curious about what happened to **W**

Comment: Thanks a lot for edit and answer. I was looking for it but without success.